# Re-ordering an ArrayList in a specific order in java

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

I have the two following `ArrayLists`:

- `orderList=[htc, apple, blackberry, karbon]`
- `dynamicList=[nokia, samsung, apple, htc, blackberry, micromax, lenova, karbon]`

While passing the `dynamicList` to the back-end, I want to re-order the elements in `dynamicList` based on the order in `orderList` in the following way.

```
dynamicList=[htc, apple, blackberry, karbon, nokia, samsung, micromax, lenova]
```

Example :
`dynamicList=[nokia, samsung, blackberry, micromax, lenova, karbon]`
Should be ordered as Follow
`dynamicList=[blackberry, karbon, nokia, samsung, micromax, lenova]`

Where should I start ?

Comment: I would pick 1st element from `orderList`, remove that element from `dynamicList`, then add it back at pos-0, etc

Comment: @RC missed your comment and added similar one as answer.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new list `finalList`. Loop over the `orderList` and check if the element is present in the `dynamicList`. If it is, `add()` it to `finalList` and remove it from `dynamicList`.

Once you're done looping over `orderList`, add the remaining elements of `dynamicList` to `finalList`.

Answer (score 0):

Sort dynamicList with a comparator which orders things according to their position in orderList. The sort must be stable in order for the remaining items to stay in their pre-sorted order.

The comparator should look something like:

return orderList.indexOf(a)-orderList.indexOf(b).

You have to add fallbacks for when the item is missing in orderList. If you want to speedup indexOf (since its O(N)) you can precompute the indexes and put them in a map keyed by the elements.

Answer (score 0):

Loop through the `orderList` and for each element if it exists in the `dynamicList` remove it and add it to position 0. That should create the dynamic list the way you want it.

Something like this:

```
    int index = 0;
    for (String item : orderList) {
        if(dynamicList.remove(item))
            dynamicList.add(index++, item);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't this add the elements of `orderList` to `dynamicList` in the reverse order?

Comment: Or you could loop backwards on `orderList` and keep adding to `0th` position like you did before. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I will create a `LinkedHashSet`.
Loop through `orderlist`, add all elements from `orderlist`. 
Then loop through `dynamicList` and all elements. Then if you want, convert it to List.

**UPDATE:** Just noticed that, the `dynamicList` may not contain all elements from `orderList`. So updated the code.

```
Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
for(String str : orderList) {
    if(dynamicList.contains(str)) {
        set.add(str);
    }
}
set.addAll(dynamicList);

System.out.println(set);
dynamicList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
System.out.println(dynamicList);
```

Answer (score 0):

`orderList = [htc,apple,blackberry,carbon]`

`dynamicList = [nokia,samsung,apple,htc,blackberry,micromax,lenovo,carbon]`

```
public void function(List order,List dynamic){
    int counter=0;
    for(Object s:order){

     /* In each iteration over the elements of order List check whether the
     element is present in the dynamicList */

        if(dynamic.contains(s)){

         //if yes then remove that element from the dynamicList

            dynamic.remove(s);

            /* add the copy of the element at first,second,third places
             respectively in the dynamicList in the successive iterations. */

            dynamic.add(counter,s);
            counter++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(dynamic);
}
```

`Output:[htc, apple, blackberry, carbon, nokia, samsung, micromax, lenovo]`

Comment: Please note that code-only answers are generally candidates for deletion because without explanation, an answer is only applicable to the specific question. *With* explanation, a reader is able to apply the relevant techniques you have to solve their own problem in future, making your answer much more useful.

Comment: @WaiHaLee thanks for the suggestion.Added the comments to clarify. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This :)

```
public static void main(String args[]){
    List<String> orderList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> dynamicList = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
    orderList.add("htc");
    orderList.add("apple");
    orderList.add("blackberry");
    orderList.add("karbon");

    dynamicList.add("nokia");
    dynamicList.add("samsung");
    dynamicList.add("apple");
    dynamicList.add("htc");
    dynamicList.add("blackberry");
    dynamicList.add("micromax");
    dynamicList.add("lenova");
    dynamicList.add("karbon");
    for (String o : orderList) {
        if(dynamicList.contains(o))
        {
            finalList.add(o);
        }
    }
    for (String d : dynamicList) {
        if(!finalList.contains(d))
        {
            finalList.add(d);
        }
    }

    for (String f : finalList) {
        System.out.println(" "+f+" ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a LinkedHashSet. It will remove duplicates and will not break the order.

```
Set<String> finalSet = new LinkedHashSet<>();
finalSet.addAll(orderList);
finalSet.addAll(dynamicList);
```

Iterate and see the results.

Thanks

Comment: What if an element is present in orderlist but not in dynamic list ? It won't work. Btw good solution if taken care of extra element in orderlist

Comment: Hi SacJn, I checked with the scenario you have mentioned. But it worked properly.

Comment: try with following list `orderList.add("htc");
   orderList.add("apple");
   orderList.add("blackberry");
   orderList.add(" karbon");
   orderList.add(" lava");`

Comment: I used following lists and it is working. orderList.add("htc");
   ' orderList.add("apple");
    orderList.add("blackberry");
    orderList.add("karbon");
    orderList.add("lava");
    dynamicList.add("nokia");
    dynamicList.add("samsung");
    dynamicList.add("apple");
    dynamicList.add("micromax");
    dynamicList.add("lenova");
    dynamicList.add("karbon");'

Comment: then you din't read my comment properly. I said that solution will work in this particular scenario but not if atleast one element of orderList is not present in dynamic List

Comment: Yes. Here "lava" is only in orderList. Not in dynamicList

Comment: so your code doesn't produce the output as desired. Anyway lets stop this discussion here